# Is I need to sign my app in android studio, to upload it to google play?

Tags: java, android

If I have apk that not made by android studio, how to sign it and upload it to google play?
Should I use just android studio to sign app
Or I can use application like "apk signar"?

Im try apk signer and some another apps but google protect stay say my app its a virous!